# Symfony2 registration form - extra created fields with jQuery are not persisted in DB only value from last input

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, symfony-forms

I want to persist into database email field all dynamically created emails input values, after  submitting the form.  Now  the problem is that - only last value is saved, from emails  field.  I don't have idea how i can fix it.

Registration controller:

```
class RegistrationFormType extends BaseType
{
  public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
  {
    $builder->add('first_name')
      ->add('last_name')
      ->add('is_company', CheckboxType::class, array(
        'label'    => 'Is company?',
        'required' => true,
      ))
      ->add('emails', TextType::class)
      ->add('add' , ButtonType::class, array('attr'=>array('class'=>'add-email')))
      ->add('department', EntityType::class, array(
        'class' => 'UserBundle:Department',
        'choice_label' => 'name',
      ));
  }
  public function getParent()
  {
    return 'FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType';
  }

  public function getBlockPrefix()
  {
    return 'custom_user_registration';
  }

  public function getName()
  {
    return $this->getBlockPrefix();
  }
}
```

jQuery funcion to add / remove  form field:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
 var wrapper         = $("div"); //Fields wrapper
 var add_button      = $(".add-email"); //Add button ID

 var x = 1; //initlal text box count
 $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
  e.preventDefault();

  console.log('Clicking Add Button');
  if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
   x++; //text box increment
   $('.add-email').parent("div").prev().append('<div><input type="text" id="fos_user_registration_form_emails" name="fos_user_registration_form[emails]" required="required"><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>');
  }
 });

 $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
  e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
 })
});


User Entity:
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="text",nullable=true)
 */
  protected $emails;

 /**
   * @return mixed
   */
  public function getEmails()
  {
    return $this->emails;
  }

  /**
   * @param mixed $emails
   */
  public function setEmails($emails)
  {
    $this->emails = $emails;
  }
```

Registration controller:

```
class RegistrationController extends BaseController
{
//  public function registerAction(Request $request)
//  {
//
//    $response = parent::registerAction( $request );
//
//    return $response;
//  }

  public function registerAction(Request $request)
  {
    $form = $this->container->get('fos_user.registration.form');
    $formHandler = $this->container->get('fos_user.registration.form.handler');
    $confirmationEnabled = $this->container->getParameter('fos_user.registration.confirmation.enabled');
    $process = $formHandler->process($confirmationEnabled);
    if ($process) {
      $user = $form->getData();

      $this->container->get('logger')->info(
        sprintf('New user registration: %s', $user)
      );

      if ($confirmationEnabled) {
        $this->container->get('session')->set('fos_user_send_confirmation_email/email', $user->getEmail());
        $route = 'fos_user_registration_check_email';
      } else {
        $this->authenticateUser($user);
        $route = 'fos_user_registration_confirmed';
      }

      $this->setFlash('fos_user_success', 'registration.flash.user_created');
      $url = $this->container->get('router')->generate($route);


      return new RedirectResponse($url);
    }
    return $this->container->get('templating')->renderResponse('FOSUserBundle:Registration:register.html.'.$this->getEngine(), array(
      'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
  }
}
```

register.html.twig (overriden from FOS User Bundle):

```
{% extends "FOSUserBundle::layout.html.twig" %}

{% block fos_user_content %}
{% include "FOSUserBundle:Registration:register_content.html.twig" %}
{% endblock fos_user_content %}
```

Comment: Can you include your `register.html` file in the question?

Comment: Cameron Hurd - done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like the fields being rendered/cloned by the js aren't having their names updated, and those that come later are overriding earlier fields with the same names.

For example, if I have a form rendered something like:

```
<!-- pseudo markup; yours will likely differ -->
<div class="form_row">
    <input type="email" name="fos_user[email]" />
</div>
<button class="add_email" onclick="javascript:[...];">Add email</button>
```

And I click that `.add-email` button, giving me:

```
<div class="form_row">
    <input type="email" name="fos_user[email]" />
</div>
<div class="form_row">
    <input type="email" name="fos_user[email]" />
    <button onclick="javascript:[...];">Remove</button>
</div>
<button class="add_email" onclick="javascript:[...];">Add email</button>
```

If I were to fill in both `<input>` fields, and submit the form, I'd essentially have have two values for the `fos_user[email]` input field. The browser takes the last one as the canonical value, ignoring all others with the same name. When the request goes out, it sends only one value field name.

To verify this hypothesis, you should examine the request data from the "network" panel in your browser's developer tools. Here's how to do that in Google Chrome: [link](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/resource-loading#view_http_headers).

[image: Pic of google chrome dev tools examining an HTTP request.]

> Pic of google chrome dev tools examining an HTTP request. Where the user has selected `remotedebugging.png`, you might look for the main POST request to `/register`, or whatever your `FOSUserBundle`'s register action is.

If this turns out to be the case - then the error lies with the way that your javascript is cloning the fields. You'll need to be certain that the fields have a tailing `[n]` on each of their `name` attributes. (Where `n` is a number.) The best way to to that is to use a collection.

But hold up... a *collection*!?. It looks like you've not primed your user model to hold a collection of emails.

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity\User;

use FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;


class User extends BaseUser
{
    ...

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text",nullable=true)
     */
    protected $emails;
```

You've named it in the plural, but it appears just like a normal string as far as Doctrine or your ORM are concerned.

### The Fix

1. Change your `User`'s `$emails` field to a `simple_array` type, which stores comma-delimited values in the db column. The example below uses a doctrine annotation, to do this. ([Here's the doctrine reference for simple_array](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/types.html#simple-array).) Other array-like options: "[array](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/types.html#array)" (stored w/ php serialization) "[json](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/types.html#json)" (stored as a json object)

   Don't discard the `$email` field, (note the singular name) as I believe `FOSUserBundle` requires it when extending their `User` model class. Be sure to update your getters and setters (as in example below), and ensure the `$emails` property of your user is an empty `ArrayCollection` object on instantiation. Run `doctrine:schema:update` from the symfony console after doing this.

   ```
   <?php
   // src/AppBundle/Entities/User.php

   namespace AppBundle\Entity\User;

   use FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User as BaseUser;
   use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

   class User extends BaseUser
   {

       ...

       /**
        * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
        */
       protected $email;

       /**
        * @ORM\Column(type="simple_array")
        */
       protected $emails;

       ...

       /**
        * Instantiate the User 
        */
       public function __construct()
       {
           parent::__construct();
           $this->emails = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
           ...
       }

       /**
        * Add an email to the collection of emails
        *
        * @param string $email The email to add.
        *
        * @return User
        */
       public function addEmail($email)
       {
           $this->emails[] = $email;

           return $this;
       }

       /**
        * Remove an email from the collection of emails
        *
        * @param string $email The email to disassociate from this user.
        *
        * @return User
        */
       public function removeEmail($email)
       {
           $this->email->removeElement($email);

           return $this;
       }

       /**
        * Get all emails in colletion
        *
        * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
        */
       public function getEmails()
       {
           return $this->emails;
       }
   ```
2. Extend your registration form further so it includes the collection field.

   ```
   <?php
   // src/AppBundle/Form/UserRegistrationType.php

   namespace AppBundle\Form;

   use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CollectionType;
   use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\EmailType;

   class RegistrationFormType extends BaseType
   {
       public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
       $builder->add(

           ...

           'emails', 
           CollectionType::class,
           [
               'entry_type' => EmailType::class,
               'allow_add'  => true,
               'allow_delete'  => true
           ],

           ...

       )

       ...

   }
   ```

   In my example, I'm extending the form outside the controller. When I extend the reg. form in FOSUserBundle, I let the bundle know in `app/config.yml`

   ```
   // app/config.yml
   ...
   fos_user:
       registration:
           form:
               type: AppBundle\Form\RegistrationFormType

   ...
   ```

   The `allow_add` key on the options array tells twig to render the `emails` field's container with a `data-prototype` attribute, which will include a `__name__` placeholder string. That placeholder will help you number your form fields more accurately, and avoid the duplicate name trap we fell into above.
3. Render the form a little differently. Pull from Symfony's recommended javascript for `CollectionType`. From http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html:

   ```
   {# '/project/base/app/Resources/FOSUserBundle/views/Registration/register_content.html.twig' #}

   {{ form_start(form) }}
       {# ... #}

       {# store the prototype on the data-prototype attribute #}
       <ul id="email-fields-list"
           data-prototype="{{ form_widget(form.emails.vars.prototype)|e }}">
       {% for emailField in form.emails %}
           <li>
               {{ form_errors(emailField) }}
               {{ form_widget(emailField) }}
           </li>
       {% endfor %}
       </ul>

       <a href="#" id="add-another-email">Add another email</a>

       {# ... #}
   {{ form_end(form) }}

   <script type="text/javascript">
       // keep track of how many email fields have been rendered
       var emailCount = '{{ form.emails|length }}';

       jQuery(document).ready(function() {
           jQuery('#add-another-email').click(function(e) {
               e.preventDefault();

               var emailList = jQuery('#email-fields-list');

               // grab the prototype template
               var newWidget = emailList.attr('data-prototype');
               // replace the "__name__" used in the id and name of the prototype
               // with a number that's unique to your emails
               // end name attribute looks like name="contact[emails][2]"
               newWidget = newWidget.replace(/__name__/g, emailCount);
               emailCount++;

               // create a new list element and add it to the list
               var newLi = jQuery('<li></li>').html(newWidget);
               newLi.appendTo(emailList);
           });
       })
   </script>
   ```

   Notice how the script replaces a prototype's `__name__` placeholder with that email's position in the form? That will render as something like:

   ```
   <div class="form_row">
       <input type="email" name="fos_user[emails][0]" />
   </div>
   <div class="form_row">
       <input type="email" name="fos_user[emails][1]" />
       <button onclick="javascript:[...];">Remove</button>
   </div>
   <button class="add_email" onclick="javascript:[...];">Add email</button>
   ```

   ... which will force the browser to treat each field individually.

Comment: If you'd like, I can expand into how you might use a `FormEvent` to set the model's `$email` field to just be the first item in the `$emails` collection. Otherwise, you'll probably run into validation issues if the the `$email` is not set explicitly.

Comment: Hi.  Cameron.  Actually your  register for  not generating any input field, for emails field,  and when you click  add new email, only li elements are added.   http://prntscr.com/cpmbcq

Comment: Have you `use`d `Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CollectionType` and `Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\EmailType`?

Comment: Its weird because when i'm not adding {{form_widget(form)}} before your email widget, im able to create  new email field  http://pastebin.com/bQ5c0YfA    but the form  looks weird: http://prntscr.com/cpni9e, and when im adding form  widget, form looks normal, but  emails field  are  not generated:  http://prntscr.com/cpninq

Comment: And very got spot  with  with emails field in doctrine,  i rename  this field to company_email,  and  im  able to save  multiple emails on it. I've change simple_array to array type.

Comment: If you feed the whole `form` var to the `form_widget` twig helper function, you'll render the whole form in one go: `form_widget(form)`. So it makes sense that you'll get an odd looking form.

Now, if you do `form_start(form)`, and then render a field or two, like you do in that pastebin, then the rest of the form gets rendered by that closing `form_end(form)` tag.

Comment: Here's a pastebin where you could render the form's fields in your preferred order, using `form_row()` for each field, in an order somewhat matching your second screenshot, http://pastebin.com/yPAWQEmd but keeping the `data-prototype` functions working appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

If you have 10 inputs with name `fos_user_registration_form[emails]`, the last one overrides the first nines. But if you change the name of e-mail field, Symfony does not recognize the field and send an error.

Solution for you: [CollectionType Field](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html). It allows you to create multiple fields for one attribute or delete existing ones. Also by default it generates `prototype` - a HTML template to insert new input into DOM.